# Bringing pages for a particular process out of swap

Tags: linux, swap

I'd like to know if it's possible to bring pages from a particular process into main memory, or to set parameters for a given process, or class of process so that it will not be swapped out.

Answer (score 4):

You can unswap a process by reading all of its memory pages.

Normally it would be a bit burdensome (reading `/proc/…/maps` to learn where are the allocated pages, then reading these pages from `/proc/…/mem`—browse `man proc` for more details), but thankfully, there's a program that already does that: `gcore`. Its goal is to dump core files, and in the process `gcore` needs to read all that memory. As we're not actually interested in the core file, we can just ask it to store it in `/dev/null` (core files can be big, so writing them on disk would make it much slower). Example:

```
gcore 22382 -o /dev/null
```

Comment: That sounds sensible. However, `gcore` (at least on debian) seems to append `.[pid]` to the file name given by `-o`, hence the `/dev/null` trick results in a permission error: `Failed to create /dev/null.22382`.

Comment: @mpy: Interesting. I checked the above command on my Debian Sid system… Maybe it is because the process has multiple threads?

Comment: I used a simple `sleep` command to test. But this was on _Debian Lenny_. Perhaps something has changed, I can recheck on _Wheezy_ later this week.

Comment: @mpy: no need to, I can reproduce this now too. Also, I found that `gcore` is just a shell wrapper over `gdb`, and that it's the shell wrapper who adds the pid to the file name… so it's a matter of editing that shell script. I'll edit my answer later.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right (I already upvoted yesterday ;). From the script `gdb -> attach PID -> gcore /dev/null -> detach -> quit` is the main essence.

Comment: Of course, by the time you get to the last pages you need to read from the process, there's no guarantee that the pages you read earliest won't have been paged out again.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is improve the performance of a process, I'd recommend [`nice`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice).

You can also influence the kernel's tendency to swap in general by setting its [swappiness](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

You might also find [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578137/can-i-tell-linux-not-to-swap-out-a-particular-processes-memory) helpful.

Comment: What I'm looking to do is avoid the lag that occurs when a process is accessed for the first time since real memory was full.  EG I have a browser tab (in chrome) displaying some static page; I open a gazillion more; main memory fills up and my original tab gets swapped out; I close the gazillion more; I do some stuff; I go to look at the original one again: it has to load from swap.  What i'd like to do is just explicitly unswap the pages containing that original tab, ie the process running it (this is in Chrome).

Comment: mlockall() and madvise() seem like they would be applicable if they worked on a per-process basis rather than a per-address basis.  I guess I could connect to the process with gdb and run mlockall().

Comment: It also seems like setting the swappiness doesn't affect how quickly pages are swapped back in?  I've changed my swappiness to 0 and still 1/6 of memory contains cache, and about 3% is free.

Comment: @intuited: So you want to look at the original page and it's in swap so you want to bring it out of swap. Well, looking at it will do that. You shouldn't need to do something explicitly that the system is going to do for you (at the same time you'd do it yourself, I might add). Your proposed `unswap` would have the same kind of lag at the same moment in time that the lag occurs already. Really, Linux does a good job of all this by itself. More RAM is one sure answer.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: The point would be to do it before the system does it.  Normally the system will wait until, as I understand it, the pages are needed before bringing them out of swap.  I'd like to say "okay, I just closed my huge Audacity project, I have a ton of free memory.. I'm going to bring a bunch of stuff that I'm going to use soon into main memory".  While the disk is chugging away I can be working on stuff that's already in memory -- ie stuff that wasn't swapped out while I was working in Audacity.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: I could just go around and click on things, but it's a hassle if there are 10 different browser tabs.  It would be better if the system took the initiative and brought some stuff back, using some kind of heuristics to guess what I would be most likely to want to use.. though it can't be expected to be telepathic, so having manual control would be useful.  However I find that it instead tends to just kind of sit there with a bunch of free memory and a bunch of stuff in swap, and then every time I go to use something I have to wait for it to read it out of swap.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: this doesn't seem to have changed with a decreased swappiness: at swappiness == 0 I've got >400MB free (not cache) and over a GB in swap.